# Ajax returns Authorization HTML instead of json object

Tags: ajax, bitrix

I've been having some issues getting my ajax calls to go through. The more confusing part is that I had it all working beautifully just yesterday, and I'm not totally sure what changed. I have several ajax calls set up. My first few calls run through fine, but it appears that what is being returned is the HTML for the Authorization page, rather than the json object that should be getting returned. Has anyone had this issue before, and if so, do you have a solution? I'm happy to share my code, but I'm not sure what showing it will explain beyond my own explanation.

Comment: look at the returned HTML code, there may be php errors in the text, so php can break the supposed json. The Bitrix component must have the parameter “AJAX_MODE” => “Y”. What components do you use? What version of bitrix?

Comment: Most updated version of Bitrix, and the components should work fine. It doesn't work regularly. Sometimes it just demands I re-log in without much warning, hence the return of the login html.